# Resizing responsive navbar using React and window.scrollY rotates between collapsed and uncollapsed at breakpoint

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, layout

I'm trying to make a responsive navbar where it resizes once it scrolls past the height of the navbar (80px currently), but once I scroll to around the point of 80px, it constantly rotates between the collapsed and uncollapsed version. I've tried messing around with the conditionals and rounding the number, but both didn't solve the issue. Could someone explain to me why this is happening and a possible solution (maybe an alternative to window.scrollY?)

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Navbar.css";

const Navbar = () => {
  const [scrolled, setScrolled] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const onScroll = () => {
      console.log("condition not rounded", window.scrollY);
      if (window.scrollY >= 80) {
        setScrolled(true);
      } else if (window.scrollY <= 79) {
        setScrolled(false);
      }
    };
    
    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="navbar-container">
      <div className={`navbar ${scrolled ? "navbar-collapse" :""}`}>
        <div>
          <NavLink className={`nav-link ${scrolled ? "nav-link-collapse": ""}`} to="/">HOME</NavLink>
        </div>
        <div>
          <NavLink className={`nav-link ${scrolled ? "nav-link-collapse": ""}`} to="/menu">MENU</NavLink>
        </div>
        <div>
          <NavLink className={`nav-link ${scrolled ? "nav-link-collapse": ""}`} to="/market">MARKET</NavLink>
        </div>
        <div>
          <NavLink className={`nav-link ${scrolled ? "nav-link-collapse": ""}`} to="/about">ABOUT US</NavLink>
        </div>
        <div>
          <NavLink className={`nav-link ${scrolled ? "nav-link-collapse": ""}`} to="/contact">CONTACT US</NavLink>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

```
.navbar-container {
  background-color: #010a10;
  height: auto;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 calc((100vw - 1000px) / 2);
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.nav-link {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFFBF2;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 1.6rem 3.5rem;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.nav-link-collapse {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.active {
  color: #c10206;
  background-color: #282829;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
  color: #c10206;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to see if you get the behaviour you want. I am fixing the scrolled version in the top right corner:

```
.navbar-collapse {
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  position: fixed; /*  add this */
  right: 0; /*  and this */
}
```

Comment: Hi, this ended up working! Could you explain why those two properties make the navbar do what it's supposed to and why position: sticky doesn't accomplish that

Comment: I am not a CSS expert, so I can't explain in detail, but position sticky is a hybrid of other positions, it behaves like static and when you scroll it can behave like absolute or fixed.  For this situation position fixed need `right: 0` but you could use `sticky` as well but you would have to change the `right: 0` for `top: 0`